# Wrong filename when printing html to pdf after KB50001330

Tags: pdf, printing, windows-10, internet-explorer-11, html-to-pdf

I am using an application that calls Internet Explorer and then prints html files to PDF format, by using CutePDF and/or Bullzip PDF.

Up to recently, if filename was my_file.html, resulting PDF filename was my_file.pdf. After KB5001330 update (Windows 10 build 19042.964) resulting filename is random eg IABG0P12.pdf (always 8 letter).

Keeping original filename is very important for the app. I found that Internet Explorer makes a copy of the original file to “%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp and renames it with a random name as I mentioned before. Then, it actually prints this copied file and not the original one...

Printing from Edge or Chrome works fine, the original filename is kept.

Any ideas how I can fix it without uninstalling the update?

Thank you

Comment: Don't use IE anymore? Its dead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved after Edge updated to 90.0.818.62

Comment: I have this exact problem, my windows and IE are 21H1 and Edge is updated to the latest. Can you elaborate more on how you fixed it? IE keeps renaming files to a random string on print.

Comment: Didn't do anything to fix it, it started working again after the updates. What my computer has now: Win 10 64bit 20H2 OS build 19042.1052. Edge version is  91.0.864.48

Comment: Well then, expect the problem to strike again once you're updated to the latest windows 10 version (21H1 19043.1055)